# Linux Upgrade (Debian) - Possible missing firmware problem

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, firmware

during the upgrade of a debian system i got the following errors:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i91
```

Has anyone encountered something similar? I tried safe update/upgrade..

Comment: If you don'ẗ have a problem with the device, you can ignore this.  If you have problems, or it doesn't work, you probably need to address this.  Just add `nonfree` repository and search which file owns the file you want.  Use `apt-file search rtl_nic/rtl8125` or `dpkg-search -S rtl_nic/rtl8125` and it tells you which package to install.

Comment: @Anders Can we also ignore the message if we see "Unable to load firmware" with dmesg command? I asked a question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768156/unable-to-load-firmware-rtl-nic-rtl8168h-2-fw-but-ethernet-card-does-not-need

Comment: @baptx if nothing "bad" happen, yes.  It depends on what kind of hardware you are using.  As usually, it depends.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's normal. Many devices need firmware to fully work. The thing is, firmware is a binary blob, and not free (as in GNU-free).

So Debian does not distribute it by default.

In your case you could do this (with the non-free entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek firmware-misc-nonfree
```

If that ever happens again, one way to know the package that holds a certain file is to look it up at packages.debian.org, under *Search the contents of packages*.

Alternatively, you can go to: https://packages.debian.org/file:path, where path is the path of the file you are looking for, for example, for `/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw` it would be:
https://packages.debian.org/file:/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw

Comment: To actually find the package where they are located, you can add to your answer the general solution to use `apt-file search rtl_nic/rtl8125` or `dpkg-search -S rtl_nic/rtl8125` to locate the package with the firmware.  And as you suggested, you need to add `nonfree` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.